# Read a text file or xml without HttpClient in angular 7

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular7

Is there any way to maintain a config file in angular? (in order to change back-end api url)

for e.g:

```
     Development - 192.168.1.50:4001
     QA          - 192.168.1.96:1111


     Client1 - 10.10.20.161:2003 <---- Bank 1

     Client2 - 192.168.1.244:1003 <---- Bank 2

     Client2 - 192.168.0.101:3003 <---- Bank 3
```

I want to change the environment according to the client without making production builds for each.

Comment: One way i know of is `var fs = require('fs');` and `fs.readFile('./src/version.json', 'utf8', function (err,data) {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can create/maintain config JS files under the `app/assets` folder:

**assets/config.js**

```
(function(window) {
    window.config = {
        __API_BASE_URL__: 'http://server1/api',
        __APP_BASE_HREF__: '/production/'
    };
})(window);
```

Then bootstrap the configuration file to override API_BASE_URL and API_BASE_HREF:

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

export const API_BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('API_BASE_URL');
declare var config: any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: API_BASE_URL, useValue: config['__API_BASE_URL__'] },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: config['__APP_BASE_HREF__'] }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When calling services, append the base API url (if it exists):

```js
import { Component, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { API_BASE_URL } from './app.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app23';
  http: HttpClient;
  baseUrl: string;
  constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) http: HttpClient, @Optional() @Inject(API_BASE_URL) baseUrl?: string) {
    this.http = http;
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl ? baseUrl : '';
    this.http.get(`${baseUrl}users`).subscribe(t => {
       ...
    });
  }
}
```

Make the necessary changes to *index.html* so that it loads `config.js` as early as possible:

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <script src="assets/config.js"></script>  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App23</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Build for production (this will compile the modules and output to the 'dist' folder):

`ng build --prod`

Finally, depending on the environment, replace config.js under the 'dist' folder as a post-build deployment step.